# Using Direct line Extension with Composer Bot?

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework, bot-framework-composer

Has someone been able to connect a composer bot with [Direct Line Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-directline-extension-node-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) . The code and samples apply only to SDK and cant find a sample for Composer and the current ones are not working within Composer bots ?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked with Microsoft and the **directline app service extension** with bot composer feature request is not enabled yet.

Something to look is below but that will be a custom solution :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/concept-extend-with-code